# Camel - Resolving ActiveMQ topic name when using wildcards

Tags: spring, apache, uri, activemq-classic, dsl

I have a scenario when I am reading from a topic based on wildcards:

```
    <route id="ReadMQ">
        <from uri="jmsep://topic:sys/*/test/request" />
```

But I need to re-route the response based on the original input topic name, say someone published on `sys/5/test/request`, I should be sending a response on `sys/5/test/response` so that I've two different different topics for request and response. As you can see, I am using spring DSL to configure my routes, I am not sure how can I configure the `<to uri=...` part dynamically. 
Please let me know if you have any clues on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with something similar and got it working using [simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html).

Note that the `jmsep://` doesn't seem correct. At least you should remove the slashes like so `jmsep:`. At least `jmsep` should be defined. In any case, in the examples below I assume you are using `jms` and topics. If this is not the case, then the example will not work. Also, `someWhere` and `someWhereElse` should be changed to the correct.

Anyway, on to the point. First let's check if a basic route is working with logging:

```
<route id="ReadMQ">
    <from uri="someWhere:topic:sys/*/test/request" />
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Received message with topic: ${header.JMSDestination.topicName}"/>
</route>
```

Send a message at `sys/5/test/request` and you should be able to get to see in `${ACTIVEMQ_DIR}/data/activemq.log` an entry like so: `Received message with topic: sys/5/test/request`.

From here on you should choose an [enterprise integration pattern](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) that suits your needs.

Maybe you can get away with the following, but I haven't tested it at all:

```
<route id="ReadMQ">
    <from uri="someWhere:topic:sys/*/test/request" />
    <to uri="someWhereElse:topic:${header.JMSDestination.topicName.replace("request", "response")}"/>
</route>
```

This again uses simple, but you can choose another language from camel.apache.org/languages.html.

Hope this helps (although I doubt that it will work).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I made it work by getting the topic name as:
`String topicName = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSDestination", String.class);`
and set the topicname by parsing out the number from input topicname:
`exchange.setProperty("MyNumber", myNumber);`
and then in the route I have my destination as:
   `<recipientList>
    <simple>jmsep://topic:pos/${property.MyNumber}/test/response
    </simple>
   </recipientList>`
But you hit the nail in the head to retrieve the input topic name :-)
Your routes looks much less messier, lemme try that out :D

Comment: If you are using Java DSL, it would be cleaner to use it for the response, too. In my answer I used only Spring DSL because you mentioned that you are looking for a way in Spring DSL.